# Express basis in terms of a subspace of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

So I have a subspace of the form W = {a$e^x$ + b$e^{-x}$} and I need to express the basis {$e^x$+$e^{-x}$, $e^x$-$e^{-2x}$}

How can I express the second argument of the basis taking into account the 2 in the exponent of e?

I know that the first argument would be a vector of the form (1,1) and the second would start (1, -?);

Comment: What do you mean by "express the base"? These two bases clearly correspond to different subspaces, since $$ae^x + b^{-x} = e^x - e^{-2x} $$ implies $a=1$ and $b=-e^{-x}$ - which is not a scalar!

Comment: @Math1000 express the basis, already edit it

Comment: @Math1000 the two bases form a basis that belongs to W

Comment: Now the question makes even less sense...